# Problem of using proxy with wget in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, wget

Please help me, I want to download file from dev.opennebula.org using command wget but I have a problem with proxy. Now, I have already set the http-proxy value in file /etc/wgetrc and I use command wget --proxy-username=username --proxy-password=password URL but the result is

```
Connecting to proxy.mmcs:8080 failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I am sure that I set the proxy name and port correctly. How can I do and can I use other commands to download that file.

Thank you.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Inside `sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc` add those lines:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

Inside `sudo gedit /etc/environment` add those lines:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
https_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

Inside `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` add those lines:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port";
```

Source: [Ubuntu Linux Proxy Settings in company environment](http://dev.hiprogrammer.com/2012/05/linix-proxy-settings-in-company.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try `--proxy-user` instead of `--proxy-username`.

Answer (score 0):

Error message says "Connection timed out". For me that looks more like error in establishing the connection the the proxy and not in authentication.

I'd start by debugging following things:

1. does proxy.mmcs resolv with "host" and can it be pinged
2. does changing proxy.mmcs into ip address help ?
3. can i telnet from same host that i try to run wget into the proxy server's port 8080.