# Docker can't connect to the internet from with proxy

Tags: linux, docker, wget, http-proxy

I have this Linux box

```
$ uname -a
Linux TOCWgfi7IC 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 16 01:56:35 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have docker running on it (someone else installed it for me, but it seems the configuration files like /etc/default/docker don't exist)

I use a proxy http and https.
I've added the proxy settings to .bashrc file and .bash_profile and I was able to pull with github. I've also added HTTP_PROXY and the lowercase version (http_proxy) to /etc/default/docker, /etc/environment, /etc/apt/apt.conf, /etc/bash.bashrc and probably others too)

My proxies are in this format:

```
http_proxy=http://proxyprd.sss.com:8080
https_proxy=https://proxyprd.sss.com:8080
```

If I use wget I can't get anything. Requests time out.

```
sudo wget https://index.docker.io/v1
--2015-07-07 13:13:33--  https://index.docker.io/v1
Resolving index.docker.io... 54.174.141.60, 54.210.36.116, 54.152.41.71
Connecting to index.docker.io|54.174.141.60|:443...
failed: Connection timed out.
```

I've looked at the docker documentation and a few SO questions and none solved the issue for me:
[Problem of using proxy with wget in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933072/problem-of-using-proxy-with-wget-in-ubuntu)

https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/#http-proxy

[Cannot download Docker images behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy)

How do I connect to the internet with docker. Do I need a username and password in the proxy line?

**EDIT 1**
Got wget to work by adding /root/.wgetrc and putting the proxies in there.
This didn't work for docker with /root/.dockerrc :(

Comment: Do you have connection to the proxy? E.g. `telnet proxyprd.sss.com 8080`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by connections... these are the url to the proxies: `http_proxy=http://proxyprd.sss.com:8080` and `https_proxy=https://proxyprd.sss.com:8080`

Comment: In order to use the proxy, you must be able to connect to it. You can test this with the command `telnet proxyprd.sss.com 8080`.

Comment: @user3584460 ya I can connect. I had issues that wget timed out but curl worked. Then I added to /root/.wgetrc the 2 proxies and it worked. I tried making a /root/.dockerrc file w the proxies but that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

This has not been answered for long, but it might help others.

```
docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://host:port --build-arg https_proxy=https://host:port -t dwp_service:0.1 dwp_services/
```

Just passing your proxy as build arguments when building the image does the trick.

Comment: you never know :) helped me right now!